# Why isn't this do while loop working properly?

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I working on a project for my course. The program runs fine until it hits my end program I've been messing with it for about 2 hours when I thought I was already finished.

This is the code it's messing up on.

```
do {
                System.out.println("Do you want to end program? (Enter n or y):");
                endProgram = Input.next();
                if(!endProgram.equals("y") || (!endProgram.equals("n"))){
                    System.out.println("Do you want to end program? (Enter n or y):");
                }
                if (endProgram.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
                    endProgram = "n";
                    aui = true;
                } 
                if (endProgram.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
                    endProgram = "y";
                    aui = true;
                }
            } while(aui = false);
```

I tried messing with the else if then switched to if. Full code is

```
public static String endProgram = null;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    
    String MUR = "--------------Monthly Use Report--------------";
    int minutesAllowed;
    int minutesUsed = 0;
    int minutesOver;
    double totalOwed;
    double monthlyRate = 74.99;
    double minOver = 0.20;
    double realOwed;
    boolean valid = false;
    boolean over = false;
    boolean aui = false;
    
    Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Cell Phone Minutes Calculator.");
    
    do {
        
        do {
            System.out.println("Please input the amount of minutes you were allowed to use per month.");
            System.out.println("Please Enter a value between (200 - 800)");

            minutesAllowed = Input.nextInt();

        } while (minutesAllowed <= 199 || minutesAllowed >= 801);{
        
    }

        do{
            try{
                System.out.println("How many minutes were used during the previous month?");
                minutesUsed = Input.nextInt();

                if(minutesUsed <= 1){
                    System.out.println("--Invalid Input! Please use a positive number.--");
                } else {
                    valid = true;
                }
            } catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Invalid Input! Please try again.");
                Input.next();
            }
        }while(!valid);
        
        minutesOver = minutesAllowed - minutesUsed;
        
        if(minutesAllowed >= minutesUsed){
            System.out.println("You were not over your minutes for the month!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You were over your minutes by "+ Math.abs(minutesOver));
            over = true;
        }
            totalOwed = (Math.abs(minutesOver))*(minOver);
            realOwed = totalOwed+monthlyRate;
        System.out.println(MUR);
        System.out.println("Minutes allowed were "+ minutesAllowed);
        System.out.println("Minutes used were "+ minutesUsed);
        if(over){
            System.out.println("Minutes over were "+ Math.abs(minutesOver));
            System.out.println("Total due is $"+ realOwed);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Total due is $"+ monthlyRate);
        }
    
      
     do {
            System.out.println("Do you want to end program? (Enter n or y):");
            endProgram = Input.next();
            if(!endProgram.equals("y") || (!endProgram.equals("n"))){
                System.out.println("Do you want to end program? (Enter n or y):");
            }
            if (endProgram.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
                endProgram = "n";
                aui = true;
            } 
            if (endProgram.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
                endProgram = "y";
                aui = true;
            }
        } while(aui = false);
      
        
    }while((endProgram.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) && (aui = false));
   
}
```

}

Sorry if the code is sloppy. When I run the Program it runs properly unless I put two improper user inputs. such as,

Program running//

> --------------Monthly Use Report--------------
>
> Minutes allowed were 450
>
> Minutes used were 500
>
> Minutes over were 50
>
> Total due is $84.99
>
> Do you want to end program? (Enter n or y):
>
> g
>
> Do you want to end program? (Enter n or y):

If I add Input.Next(); to nest if statement to

```
if(!endProgram.equals("y") || (!endProgram.equals("n"))){
                    System.out.println("Do you want to end program? (Enter n or y):");
                    endProgram = Input.next();
```

it displays it correctly. I tried messing with the massive do while loop that goes across the whole project. If anybody can help me it will be much appreciated. Sorry if this is confused I'll respond if you guys have any questions. Thanks in advance for any response and sorry for the inconveniences.

Answer (score 5):

Replace

```
while (aui = false); //here you are assigning aui to false value
```

to

```
while (aui == false); //here you are comparing aui to false value
```

`=` is as assignment operator, `==` is comparison operator.

The best practise is to use boolean directly, not by comparing:

```
while (!aui);
```

Comment: Always prefer to use boolean values directly rather than comparing them to each other.  `while (!aui)` is easier to read and harder to make mistakes with than `while (aui == false)`.

Comment: @azurefrog yes, that is the best practice.

Comment: Thanks a bunch I was sitting here and I know it was something simple two hours wasted... Thanks a ton guys!

Comment: The appropriate action would have been to vote to close the question as a duplicate or as a typo.